# endless loop in Quicksort

Tags: c, quicksort

I was implementing the `Quicksort Algorithm`, but I have some `error` and I'm not able to figure out.
I'm using the `rand()` function to generate random numbers. I'm limiting these numbers in `mod(100)`. `mod (100)` works well but when I make it `mod(10)` it doesn't work. The program runs but stops after printing the random unsorted array.

**Here's my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int a[50];
void quicksort(int l, int r)
{
    int s;
    if(l<r)
    {
        s=partition(l, r);
        quicksort(l, s-1);
        quicksort(s+1, r);
    }
}

int partition(int l, int r)
{
    int p, i, j, temp;
    p = a[l];
    i=l;
    j=r+1;
    while(i<=j)
    {
        while(a[i]<=p && i<r+1)
            i=i+1;
        while(a[j]>=p && j>l)
            j=j-1;
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }
    temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
    temp = a[l];
    a[l] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
    return j;
}
int main()
{
    int n, i;
    printf("Enter number of elements: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Random Array: \n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand()%100; // The error seems to be here for rand()%10
        printf("%d  ", a[i]);
    }
    quicksort(0,n-2);
    printf("\n Solution: \n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't show how you limit `n` to 1..50 (but you need to).  Does the fact that you've probably got many duplicates when you've got only values 0..9 whereas you have few duplicates when you've got value 0..99 suggest anything?

Comment: Hmm; intriguing.  The 0..9 code seems to work OK up to n = 31; from n = 32 onwards, it fails (it takes a long time to finish if it does finish; I never waited long enough).  The 0..99 code fails for me starting at n = 49.

Comment: You get the same error with `%100` often enough.

Comment: Hmmmm; even more intriguing.  I added `srand(time(0));` to give different sequences of random numbers, and then changed it to print the seed.  I then got it jamming on 0..9 with only 7 entries — two sequences gave trouble so far: `9  6  9  2  9  7  2` and `9  2  5  4  3  9  2`.  With the first of those, it entered the partition code and never came back.  If you can reproduce what I see, that should give you a good way to debug what the trouble is.  (When I'm working on "random" sequences, I find it helpful to provide myself a mechanism to print the seed, and also a mechanism to set the seed.)

Comment: Please explain in `quicksort(0,n-2);` the "-2". Please explain in `j=r+1;` the "+1". Do so by adding a comment to the code, I recommend.

Comment: @Yunnosch: the pair of peculiar numbers more or less work together to end up so the sort and partition operates on elements 0..n-1, which are the correct indexes for the first and last elements of an array of n elements.  But I agree that is peculiar notation.

Comment: I would prefer OP to explain. ;-) The point is, if I do `j=r;` it seems to work. And if I do `quicksort(0,n-1);` it seems to work without even using any funny negative indexes.

Comment: I'd like the OP to explain why they did it like that.  I won't be surprised to find it is a factor in the problem with the specific set of numbers I found.

Comment: @apps: FYI — when I add monitoring code to the partition with the sequence `9 6 9 2 9 7 2`, printing `i` and `j` after the loops that adjust them, I get: `Random Array:` — `9  6  9  2  9  7  2` —
`-->> QS: 0..5` —
`-->> PT: 0..6` —
`---- PT: i = 6` —
`---- PT: j = 6` —
`---- PT: i = 6` —
`---- PT: j = 6` and it continues with both `i` and `j` set to 6.  Your problem is to work out how to fix that.  It may not be a coincidence that that partition value is 9, the maximum value.

Comment: Based on the OP's problem statement, I wonder if the problem hasn't got something to do with stdout not being flushed? The program seems to work for me (`rand()%10` or `rand()%100`), even with or without the goofy indexing.

Comment: @jwdonahue: unless you added something, the code doesn't call `srand()` to seed the sequence, so it works with the same sequence each time it is called.  I am confident it is not a buffering problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop condition inside `partition()` can end up in an endless loop:

```
while(i<=j)
```

To avoid change it to

```
while(i<j)
```

It never needs to swap at two identical indexes anyway.

Comment: That fix works for me too — I didn't write it up (in time), that's all.

Comment: :-) Nice to know. Anything to add? I would give credit of course. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Nothing to add — my comments to the question show the results I got from instrumenting the code my way (add print statements).  Running in a debugger would work too, but might be harder.  Getting the problem reproducible on a small data set (7 entries) was a major breakthrough.  The peculiar call sequence and adjustment in partition should be fixed, too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I understand you recommend changing the call sequence and partitioning, but do not consider it a needed part of the answer.

Comment: I've not managed to get the sort to break even with n = 1 or n = 2, so it can survive the abuse.  Documenting what the parameters are is painful, though. "Call `quicksort()` with the start index in the array, and one less than the maximum index that can be accessed"?  Just as well the arguments are signed `int` and not unsigned `size_t`, too.  The interface is bad — but can survive as long as you know that's how to call it. OK for a one-off (sort of); not OK for anyone else to use. The fix isn't hard, either — change the `- 2` into `- 1` in the call; change the `j + 1` to `j` in `partition()`.